# Animating Pie Progress with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, caanimation

**Problem:**

If you take a look at my current code, you'll see that it works fine if `targetSeconds` is higher than ~2-3 seconds.

However, it will not work if `targetSeconds` is 0.005 seconds because there's no way it can finish 100 method calls in 0.005 seconds. Therefore, does anyone have any suggestions to what I can do to improve it? I'd rather not include third party GitHub repositories.

**Current code:**

```
// Target seconds means the seconds that it'll take to become 100.0f.    
- (void)startAnimatingWithTargetSeconds:(NSTimeInterval)targetSeconds{
// Try to set timeInterval to 0.005f and you'll see that it won't finish in 0.005f
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:targetSeconds / 100.0f target:self selector:@selector(animateWithTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


- (void)animateWithTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
  BOOL isFinished = self.currentProgress >= 100;

  if (isFinished) {
    // Invalidate timer
    if (timer.isValid) {
      [timer invalidate];
    }

    // Reset currentProgress
    self.currentProgress = 0.0f;
   }else{
     if (timer.isValid) {
        self.currentProgress += 1;
     }
  }
}

// Overriden setter
- (void)setCurrentProgress:(CGFloat)currentProgress {
  if (_currentProgress == currentProgress) {
    return;
  }

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    _currentProgress = currentProgress;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
  });
}
```

And then in `drawRect`, I have an `UIBezierPath` that basically draws the circle depending on `self.currentProgress`.

Something like this: `CGFloat endAngle = (self.currentProgress / 100.0f) * 2 * M_PI + startAngle;`

**Question:**

Is there any formula or anything that'll help me in my case? Because if I were to set `self.currentProgress` to `self.currentProgress += 5;` instead of `1`, it'll animate a lot faster, which is precisely what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when would you want to redraw every 0.005 seconds? That's 200 FPS, way more than you need.

Don't reinvent the wheel – leverage Core Animation! Core Animation already knows how to call your state change function at the proper rate, and how to redraw views as necessary, assuming you tell it what to do. The gist of this strategy is as follows:

1. Add a dynamic property to your layer that represents the completeness of your pie slice.
2. Tell Core Animation that this property can be animated by either overriding [`actionForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410844-actionforkey?language=objc), or setting the animation into the [`actions`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410789-actions?language=objc) dictionary (or even more options, detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/ReactingtoLayerChanges/ReactingtoLayerChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH7-SW2)).
3. Tell Core Animation that changes to this property require redraws of the layer using [`needsDisplayForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410769-needsdisplayforkey?language=objc).
4. Implement the [`display`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410926-display?language=objc) method to redraw the pie based on the *presentation layer's* value of your dynamic property.

Done! Now you can animate the dynamic property from any value to any other, just as you would opacity, position, etc. Core Animation takes care of the timing and the callbacks, and you get a buttery smooth 60 FPS.

For some examples, see the following resources, listed in order of decreasing usefulness (in my opinion):

- [Animating Pie Slices using a custom CALayer](https://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/) – this is basically what you want to do
- [Animating Custom Layer Properties](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animating-custom-layer-properties/) – better written but a bit less applicable
- [Apple's Core Animation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH1-SW1) – esoteric, but worth a read if you want to master the strange beast that is Core Animation

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for very **detailed** response, @ravron

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use something like this, because timer (and usleep) on small intervals works very inaccurately:

```
-(void)startAnimatingWithTargetSeconds:(NSTimeInterval)targetSeconds
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        float fps = 60;
        float currentState = 0;
        float frameStateChange = fps/targetSeconds;
        NSDate *nextFrameDate = [NSDate date];
        while (currentState < 1) {
            currentState += frameStateChange;
            self.currentProgress = roundf(currentState * 100.);
            nextFrameDate = [nextFrameDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:1./fps];
            while ([nextFrameDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
                usleep((useconds_t)(100000/fps));
            }
        }
        self.currentProgress = 0;
    });
}
```